# Android keyboard hiding the screen

Tags: c#, android, keyboard, xamarin

I am developing an android application using Xamarin C# where we are using axml layout file to display a page on a tablet. Everything is working fine except with the problem that when i am open the keyboard, it hides the page underneath the keyboard.

Is there any way using which i can view the keyboard and move the page at the top visable screen which could be scrolble so the user can scroll up and down to view the whole page.

Thanks and Regards

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:orientation="vertical"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:id="@+id/MLinerLay"
    p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
    p1:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ScrollView
        p1:id="@+id/scrollFrame"
        p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
        p1:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <WebView
            p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
            p1:layout_height="match_parent"
            p1:id="@+id/webPay" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my layout file

Comment: In android built in control is there for scrolling 'ScrollView'.

Comment: Yes, I have "ScrollView".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` , under the **activity** enter the following line:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

Hope, it will work.

Comment: I added the code '<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />' under '<manifest>' but did't make any difference

Comment: Can you attach your screen shots?

Comment: And it doesn't bring the screen up in the webview.

Comment: Using adjustResize instead of adjustPan,  The framework will always try to keep the focused element on-screen by scrolling any parent views if necessary.

If your EditText field is not nested in some sort of scrolling container such as a ScrollView then your layout may be too tall to completely display when the keyboard resizes your activity. Try wrapping your form's layout in a ScrollView. This will also allow your app's content to scroll if it is running on a smaller screen device where it may have similar issues.

Comment: I have noticed that my EditText and everything else wasn't in a ScrollView. Maybe that's why it's not scrollable. Thanks for you help. Really appreciated
.

Answer (score 2):

Add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" to your activity tag in the manifest.